# Non-linear multivariate time-series response prediction using RNN

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, prediction, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to predict the hygrothermal response of a wall, given the interior and exterior climate. Based on literature research, I believe this should be possible with RNN but I have not been able to get good accuracy.

The dataset has 12 input features (time-series of exterior and interior climate data) and 10 output features (time-series of hygrothermal response), both containing hourly values for 10 years. This data was created with hygrothermal simulation software, there is no missing data.

Dataset features:
[image: Input features]

Dataset targets:
[image: Output features]

Unlike most time-series prediction problems, I want to predict the response for the full length of the input features time-series at each time-step, rather than the subsequent values of a time-series (eg financial time-series prediction). I have not been able to find similar prediction problems (in similar or other fields), so if you know of one, references are very welcome.

---

I think this should be possible with RNN, so I am currently using LSTM from Keras. Before training, I preprocess my data the following way:

1. Discard first year of data, as the first time steps of the hygrothermal response of the wall is influenced by the initial temperature and relative humidity.
2. Split into training and testing set. Training set contains the first 8 years of data, the test set contains the remaining 2 years.
3. Normalise training set (zero mean, unit variance) using `StandardScaler` from Sklearn. Normalise test set analogously using mean an variance from training set.

This results in: `X_train.shape = (1, 61320, 12)`, `y_train.shape = (1, 61320, 10)`, `X_test.shape = (1, 17520, 12)`, `y_test.shape = (1, 17520, 10)`

As these are long time-series, I use stateful LSTM and cut the time-series as explained [here](https://github.com/ahstat/deep-learning/blob/master/rnn/4_lagging_and_stateful.py), using the `stateful_cut()` function. I only have 1 sample, so `batch_size` is 1. For `T_after_cut` I have tried 24 and 120 (24*5); 24 appears to give better results. This results in `X_train.shape = (2555, 24, 12)`, `y_train.shape = (2555, 24, 10)`, `X_test.shape = (730, 24, 12)`, `y_test.shape = (730, 24, 10)`.

Next, I build and train the LSTM model as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, 
               batch_input_shape=(batch_size,T_after_cut,features), 
               return_sequences=True,
               stateful=True,
               ))
model.addTimeDistributed(Dense(targets)))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam())

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=batch=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

Unfortunately, I don't get accurate prediction results; not even for the training set, thus the model has high bias.

[The prediction results of the LSTM model for all targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hSVV.jpg)

---

How can I improve my model? I have already tried the following:

1. Not discarding the first year of the dataset -> no significant difference
2. Differentiating the input features time-series (subtract previous value from current value) -> slightly worse results
3. Up to four stacked LSTM layers, all with the same hyperparameters -> no significant difference in results but longer training time
4. Dropout layer after LSTM layer (though this is usually used to reduce variance and my model has high bias) -> slightly better results, but difference might not be statistically significant

Am I doing something wrong with the stateful LSTM? Do I need to try different RNN models? Should I preprocess the data differently?

Furthermore, training is very slow: about 4 hours for the model above. Hence I am reluctant to do an extensive hyperparameter gridsearch...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the end, I managed to solve this the following way:

- Using more samples to train instead of only 1 (I used 18 samples to train and 6 to test)
- Keep the first year of data, as the output time-series for all samples have the same 'starting point' and the model needs this information to learn
- Standardise both input and output features (zero mean, unit variance). I found this improved prediction accuracy and training speed
- Use stateful LSTM as described [here](https://github.com/ahstat/deep-learning/blob/master/rnn/4_lagging_and_stateful.py), but add reset states after epoch (see below for code). I used `batch_size = 6` and `T_after_cut = 1460`. If `T_after_cut` is longer, training is slower; if `T_after_cut` is shorter, accuracy decreases slightly. If more samples are available, I think using a larger `batch_size` will be faster.
- use CuDNNLSTM instead of LSTM, this speed up the training time x4!
- I found that more units resulted in higher accuracy and faster convergence (shorter training time). Also I found that the GRU is as accurate as the LSTM tough converged faster for the same number of units.
- Monitor validation loss during training and use early stopping

The LSTM model is build and trained as follows:

```py
def define_reset_states_batch(nb_cuts):
  class ResetStatesCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
      self.counter = 0

    def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs={}):
    # reset states when nb_cuts batches are completed
      if self.counter % nb_cuts == 0:
        self.model.reset_states()
      self.counter += 1

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    # reset states after each epoch
      self.model.reset_states()
      return(ResetStatesCallback)    

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.CuDNNLSTM(256, batch_input_shape=(batch_size,T_after_cut ,features),
  return_sequences=True,
  stateful=True))
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(targets, activation='linear')))

optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.002)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)

earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.005, patience=15, verbose=1, mode='auto')
ResetStatesCallback = define_reset_states_batch(nb_cuts)
model.fit(X_dev, y_dev, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=1, shuffle=False, validation_data=(X_eval,y_eval), callbacks=[ResetStatesCallback(), earlyStopping])
```

This gave me very statisfying accuracy (R2 over 0.98):
[image: Prediction]
This figure shows the temperature (left) and relative humidity (right) in the wall over 2 years (data not used in training), prediction in red and true output in black. The residuals show that the error is very small and that the LSTM learns to capture the long-term dependencies to predict the relative humidity.

Comment: I am not trying to forecast, I try to predict a response sequence based on the input sequences. The input and output sequences are simultaneous. y[t1] is the response on X[t1] and in turn, y[t1] is important to predict the response y[t2] on X[t2], and so on. Thus, based on the input sequence, I can predict the whole output sequence.